# Can actionscript determine type of media stream (mp3 or flv)?

Tags: flash, stream, media

I develop stream aduio player on Adobe Flash. It receives list of stream urls and plays them by user choice. These streams may be in MP3 or FLV formats. How player can determine what type of stream audio in the URL?

Comment: What do you use to play your stream (NetStream, FLVPlayback, ... ) ?

Comment: Sound for MP3 and NetStream for FLV

Comment: I don't understand why you need to know the type of your media stream if you play the mp3 with `Sound` and the flv with `NetStream` ( you already know the type of the stream ) ?

Comment: I need to know the type of media to select Sound or NetStream.

Comment: In that case you can use the file extension.

Comment: I have not file extensions, because I play streams, not files.

Comment: But why you didn't put all these details in your question with some code examples from the first ?!